# How to connect to Teradata using SoapUI? What are the configuration details for SoapUI-Teradata connection?

Tags: jdbc, soapui, teradata

[image]I want to add a test step in Soap UI Test Case, wherein I can connect to Teradata database and fire a query to validate. 
However, I am facing issues while setting up the configuration for the connection.

In the configuration details, I have provided as below:

> Driver: com.teradata.jdbc.TeraDriver
>
> Connection String: jdbc:teradata:

Below is the error thrown on TEST CONNECTION:

> Can't get the Connection for specified properties; java.sql.SQLException: 
>      [Teradata JDBC Driver] [TeraJDBC 15.10.00.35] [Error 1032] [SQLState HY000] 
>      Single Sign-On NOT supported for Mechanism TD2.

Note: 
1. I have NOT added any properties(Name/Value).
2. SoapUI 5.3.0. (Free) version. 
3. Teradata drivers(terajdbc4, tdjssconfig jars) are added in ../SmartBear/SoapUI-5.3.0/bin/ext/

Comment: I know exactly nothing about SoapUI, but unless it can challenge you for an ID and password, you'll need to include that in your JDBC url.  Here's a link to the documentation:
 https://developer.teradata.com/doc/connectivity/jdbc/reference/current/jdbcug_chapter_2.html#BABJIHBJ

Comment: Have you restarted SoapUI after placing the driver file in the mentioned directory? Are using Jdbc test step or Groovy script test step?

Comment: Rao, Yes, I did restart SoapUI after placing the driver files in resp. directory. And I am used JDBC test step.

Comment: Andrew, I did try to go through the documentation that had shared. But I couldn't figure it out exaclty what needs to provided in the test step for connection.

Comment: I've added a picture of the JDBC test step for your reference.

Comment: After providing Connection String as: jdbc:teradata://url/dbname,user=username,password=password
I get the below error
"Can't get the Connection for specified properties; java.sql.SQLException: [Teradata JDBC Driver] [TeraJDBC 16.20.00.06] [Error 1536] [SQLState HY000] Invalid connection parameter name dbname,USER"

Comment: Try fully-qualifying the database parameter: jdbc:teradata://<servername>/database=<databasename>,USER=<username>,PASSWORD=<password>  this notation should be supportable since JDBC TD 14.00

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out. Here is the solution.
**Driver**=com.teradata.jdbc.TeraDriver
**Connection String**=jdbc:teradata://servername/USER=username,PASSWORD=password

The issue was with incorrect syntax for Connection String. 

Thanks all for your inputs!